# Compatibility of Toshiba Satellite L855/L875 with Intel/AMD hybrid graphics?

Tags: ati, hybrid-graphics

Has anyone tested the Linux compatibility for the new Toshiba Satellite L855/L875 laptops with Intel/AMD hybrid graphics? Are the proprietary ATI drivers working? Is Bumblebee working for them?

Comment: Bumblebee currently does not have full support for AMD hybrids. That issue is tracked on https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/52

Answer (score 1):

ONLY install 64-bit version of Ubuntu on this computer, the 32-bit version doesn't work:

A friend of mine just bought a "Toshiba Satellite L875D-103" (in Norway). He wanted me to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it. I have installed Ubuntu on several computers and been using Ubuntu for several years. But this laptop gave me some headache. Wireless does not work, sound does not work -and worst of all it tends to "hang" occasionally. In addition the touchpad and/or keyboard tends to "stop working" (the external mouse still function).
Because of the keyboard problem there was real pain just installing Ubuntu, using it is impossible as for now. When it freezes the mouse pointer still lives -but nothing else.
Tried with and without the ATI Catalyst driver -no change whatsoever.
As for testing anything it's impossible as it hangs too often. (As I said, even the installation was a pain as it hung and/or keyboard stopped working.)
This laptop is working fine with Windows 7. But who wants to use THAT!?

The 64-bit version is working (also with the AMD Catalyst driver which let you choose(manually) between hybrid graphics.) Read below to get the wireless working.

Comment: I have re-installed with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and it's actually (almost) working. (The first time I installed the 32-bit -bad idea). "Everything" seems to work now, except wifi. Trying to fix that...

Comment: This answer will help install the wireless driver: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163141/drivers-for-realtek-wireless-module-for-toshiba-c850-a965

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer on a Toshiba Satellite L855 which I bought new 2 weeks ago. Ubuntu 12.04 installed very nicely from a DVD, alongside Windows7 (dual boot). I'm running it with an additional (external) display (this works flawlessly over HDMI).

So far I've seen no problems whatsoever, except: Only the wireless networks card works out of the box, not the wired network. At the moment I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit works well except the wireless on toshiba satellite L875-S7208.   Wireless connects briefly (30 secs or so) then quits.

Answer (score 1):

I have Toshiba Satellite L855-14J.

Hybrid graphic is not working. It's not about Ubuntu - Toshiba didn't make graphic switchable.

So, you can't use Intel graphics built in processor, but AMD graphic card and drivers are working fine.

I think only hope is new BIOS update, but I'm not big optimist because I find Toshiba support and general quality quite messed up.