# Can't find the wireless network on toshiba satellite? 

Tags: wireless, toshiba

I bought new Toshiba satellite C870-10L and just installed Ubuntu 12.04. However, I can't find any wireless connection.
I have following hardware for networking:

```
Integrated Ethernet 10/100 Ethernet  
Wireless Integrated wireless 802.11bgn
```

This is what I have tried so far in terminal (commands and output given below):

1. lspci -vvv

   ```
        00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Capabilities: <access denied>

               00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
                   Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
                   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
               I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
               Memory behind bridge: c2000000-c2ffffff
               Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000bfffffff
               Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
               BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA+ MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: pcieport
               Kernel modules: shpchp

           00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 42
               Region 0: Memory at c3100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

           00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
               Region 0: Memory at c3114000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: mei
               Kernel modules: mei

           00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
               Region 0: Memory at c3119000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

           00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 47
               Region 0: Memory at c3110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
               Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

           00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Bus: primary=00, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
               I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-00000fff
               Memory behind bridge: fff00000-000fffff
               Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
               Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
               BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: pcieport
               Kernel modules: shpchp

           00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
               I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
               Memory behind bridge: c3000000-c30fffff
               Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fff00000-00000000000fffff
               Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
               BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: pcieport
               Kernel modules: shpchp

           00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Bus: primary=00, secondary=09, subordinate=0e, sec-latency=0
               I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
               Memory behind bridge: c1000000-c1ffffff
               Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000c0ffffff
               Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
               BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
                   PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: pcieport
               Kernel modules: shpchp

           00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
               Region 0: Memory at c3118000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

           00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

           00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0
               Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 41
               Region 0: I/O ports at 5048 [size=8]
               Region 1: I/O ports at 5054 [size=4]
               Region 2: I/O ports at 5040 [size=8]
               Region 3: I/O ports at 5050 [size=4]
               Region 4: I/O ports at 5020 [size=32]
               Region 5: Memory at c3117000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: ahci

           00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 10
               Region 0: Memory at c3115000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
               Region 4: I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
               Kernel modules: i2c-i801

           01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler LE [AMD Radeon HD 6625M Graphics] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 45
               Region 0: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
               Region 2: Memory at c2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
               Region 4: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
               Expansion ROM at c2040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: radeon
               Kernel modules: radeon

           01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb41
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 46
               Region 0: Memory at c2020000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
               Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

           08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8723
               Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 0723
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
               Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
               Region 2: Memory at c3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>

           09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
               Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device fb37
               Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
               Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
               Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
               Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 43
               Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
               Region 2: Memory at c0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
               Region 4: Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
               Capabilities: <access denied>
               Kernel driver in use: r8169
               Kernel modules: r8169
   ```
2. lsmod

   ```
   Module                  Size  Used by
       ums_realtek            17920  0 
       uas                    17828  0 
       usb_storage            39646  1 ums_realtek
       snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
       sparse_keymap          13658  0 
       bnep                   17830  2 
       rfcomm                 38139  0 
       bluetooth             158438  10 bnep,rfcomm
       parport_pc             32114  0 
       ppdev                  12849  0 
       snd_hda_codec_realtek   174222  1 
       snd_hda_intel          32765  5 
       snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
       snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
       snd_pcm                80845  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
       psmouse                72919  0 
       serio_raw              13027  0 
       snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
       snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
       snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
       snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
       joydev                 17393  0 
       uvcvideo               67203  0 
       snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
       radeon                737789  4 
       videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
       snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
       video                  19068  0 
       ttm                    65344  1 radeon
       drm_kms_helper         45466  1 radeon
       drm                   197692  6 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
       toshiba_bluetooth      12711  0 
       wmi                    18744  0 
       snd                    62064  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
       mac_hid                13077  0 
       i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 radeon
       soundcore              14635  1 snd
       snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
       mei                    36570  0 
       lp                     17455  0 
       parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
       usbhid                 41906  0 
       r8169                  56321  0 
       hid                    77367  1 usbhid
   ```
3. ifconfig -a

   ```
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:1a:2f:e7  
             inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
             inet6 addr: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe1a:2fe7/64 Scope:Link
             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
             RX packets:584588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:335858 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
             RX bytes:801442328 (801.4 MB)  TX bytes:24323663 (24.3 MB)
             Interrupt:43 Base address:0xe000 

   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
             RX packets:991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
             TX packets:991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
             RX bytes:119419 (119.4 KB)  TX bytes:119419 (119.4 KB)
   ```
4. iwconfig

   ```
   lo        no wireless extensions.

   eth0      no wireless extensions.
   ```
5. sudo lshw -class network

   ```
   [sudo] password for tryggvi: 
     *-network UNCLAIMED     
          description: Network controller
          product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
     *-network
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
          logical name: eth0
          version: 05
          serial: 4c:72:b9:1a:2f:e7
          size: 100Mbit/s
          capacity: 100Mbit/s
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
          resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0004000-c0004fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
   ```
6. rfkill list all
7. sudo lshw -class network

   ```
   [sudo] password for tryggvi: 
     *-network UNCLAIMED     
          description: Network controller
          product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3000000-c3003fff
     *-network
          description: Ethernet interface
          product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
          vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
          logical name: eth0
          version: 05
          serial: 4c:72:b9:1a:2f:e7
          size: 100Mbit/s
          capacity: 100Mbit/s
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
          configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
          resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0004000-c0004fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try:
[Drivers for Realtek wireless module for Toshiba C850-A965?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163141/drivers-for-realtek-wireless-module-for-toshiba-c850-a965)

or

[Wireless card Realtek RTL8723AE-BT is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized)

It works for me. But wireless speed is not the best!