# Toshiba L955D-107 No wireless connection detected

Tags: wireless, toshiba-satellite

I have tried everything I have read about this. The problem is I can't find out what card it is. The only thing that comes up is Realtek Semiconductor Corporation. There are no name on the card. No resctricted drivers shows up.

I have tried the solutions here and from other sites. When I tried them, I get error 1 and 2.

I have managed to install the wired network, by using the suggestions found here. But every solution for wireless fails with the errors 1 and 2.

Can anyone please help me?

Here is the output of sudo lshw -C net:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0100000-f013ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

And here is the reason for the error 2, I have to search to find out which one gave me error 1:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/build M=/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-22-generic'
CC [M]  /home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:
/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in make[2]: *** [/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-22-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have found out that the wireless card is called rtl8723ae.

When I looked at the homepage for toshiba, then I found that this laptop is delivered with ubuntu or windows 8. So it is a mystery that it wont work.
The one with ubuntu was not available in my country.

I see from other posts that it should work in 12.04. Do I have to downgrade from 12.10 to 12.04?
This is where I found that information: [Drivers for Realtek wireless module for Toshiba C850-A965?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163141/drivers-for-realtek-wireless-module-for-toshiba-c850-a965?rq=1)

Comment: @guntbert I have updated my first post.

Comment: As far as I see it, there is only one real error: the compiler complains about an *undeclared identifier* in line 320 of */home/kenneth/Nedlastinger/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c*. That means that there is something wrong within the c-code of that module - maybe some #include ??

Comment: I don't know. Really, I don't understand any of the things I added to the question. That is why I asked for help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the later version of the driver tarball named:
rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012

That should fix the compile error.  After the make completes, run

```
 sudo make install
```

and then check that the two rtl8723...bin firmware files got copied to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
Do it yourself (files are in the tarball/firmware directory) use sudo cp  to copy them.

Better yet, use 13.04, that comes with working wireless and ethernet.