# Can Ubuntu 13.10 be installed on Toshiba C840 (wifi: Realtek RTL8723AE)?

Tags: toshiba-satellite

a year ago, i'm try ubuntu 12.10 but it do'nt accept my wifi card: 
Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC (not RTL8723AE-BT)
Update: My laptop: toshiba C840

my question: does ubuntu 13.10 support my wifi card? or any ideal help me?
Thanks you so much!

Comment: Yes it supports,follow http://askubuntu.com/questions/163141/drivers-for-realtek-wireless-module-for-toshiba-c850-a965 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/139632/wireless-card-realtek-rtl8723ae-bt-is-not-recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 or later supports your 8723ae out of the box.  No need to download or compile anything.